# Problem of VMTest

Tags: test

Recently I implement the EVM, but when I check the test suit of VMTest. I found that if the storage of key and value are both 0x00, the storage is empty in the "post" section after executing the opcode "PUSH1 0x00 SSTORE" (600055).
The attachment below is the example of test suit "iszero0.json".[image: When the storage of key and value are both 0x00, the storage is empty]